# Search range for spcific name in cells than in another cell output there placement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, contains

What I would like to do in my excel workbook is search for the entire sheet for the name sam. If sam is contained I would like the specific cell placement to be printed out in cell d12. So I assume cell d12 will have some kind of formula to do this. The photo below shows exactly what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution similar like this:
`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF($1:$10="a",ADDRESS(ROW($1:$10),COLUMN($1:$10)),""))`

[image]

PS  As you mention you want to search the whole sheet I recommend you to search from a different sheet to the data sheet, so you will not cope with circular reference.

To not show the `$` in the result you could use:
`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF($1:$10="a",ADDRESS(ROW($1:$10),COLUMN($1:$10),4),""))`

Alternate to volatile `ADDRESS` function that recalculates on each change you could use the following as suggested by Scott Craner:  `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($C$2:$E$8="Sam",CHAR(COLUMN($C$2:$E$8)+64)&ROW($C$2:$E$8),""))`.
Note that if the column number of a matching value exceeds 27 it'll return wrong results.

Comment: I thought of that at first too. But then I figured if you exceed 27 columns it'd get complicated. So I switched to `ADDRESS`

Comment: Edited the answer to show both solutions and explain the pros and cons.